# ReactJS Pass key with an onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an image gallery where I loop trough image objects and I want to pass the `i` to my onClick function. This is my image gallery code:

```
<div className="gallery clearfix">
  { block.gallery.map((item, i) => (
    i < 1 ?
     <div className="gallery-image" key={i} onClick={this.toggle}>
       <a href='' className="inner">
          <img src={item.images.thumbnail_sm} alt={block.title} srcSet={`${item.images.thumbnail_md} 1x, ${item.images.thumbnail_lg} 2x`} className="img-fluid image"/>
       </a>          
     </div>
     : null
     ))}
     <div className="gallery-thumbs">
       <div className="row">
        { block.gallery.map((item, i) => (
          i > 0 && i < (limit + 1) ?
          <div className="gallery-item" key={i} onClick={this.toggle}>
          <a href='' className="inner">
            <img src={item.images.thumbnail_sm} alt={block.title} srcSet={`${item.images.thumbnail_md} 1x, ${item.images.thumbnail_lg} 2x`} className="img-fluid image" title="" />
              { block.gallery.length > (limit + 1) && i == limit ?
                <div className="img-overlay">
                   <span className="img-indicator">{ block.gallery.length - (limit + 1) }+ <span className="hidden-xs">Foto's</span></span>
                </div>
             : null 
            }
          </a>
        </div>
        : null
        ))}
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is my reactstrap modal where I want to show the image which is clicked:

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
      <ModalBody>            
        <img src={block.gallery[this.state.clickedImage].item.images.thumbnail_lg}/>
      </ModalBody>
    </Modal>
```

And here is the toggle function where I want to pass the clickedImage id:

```
toggle(id) {
    this.setState({
      clickedImage: id,
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }
```

Comment: You need to either `onClick={this.toggle.bind(this, i)}`or store `data-index={i}` on the tag (retrieve with `+event.target.dataset.index`)

Comment: @Matt could you give me an example?

Comment: Replace `onClick={this.toggle}` -> `onClick={this.toggle.bind(this, i)}`. Your `toggle` is expecting an `id` as first parameter, but since it's an event handler, it will get an `event` object as first parameter instead. The `bind` will change this so `toggle` receives `id, event` parameters, but it's a new function per index per render.

Comment: a bootstrap react example: https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/2ub6rmkc/

Comment: @Matt that is not working `
core.js:119  error TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined(…)`

Comment: @free-soul that is useless because I use the reactstrap modal and that uses the state isOpen so I cant toggle it on id

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer `block.gallery[this.state.clickedImage]` is probably null then. Log out `this.state.clickedImage` to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best practice, I don't suggest binding within onClick, that cause it invoke bind every time when it's clicked. if you are using ES6, instead you should bind it in constructor:

```
Class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }
}
```

and

```
<div className="gallery-item" key={i} onClick={(i) => this.toggle(i)}></div>
```

UPDATE: like comments say. this is actually is not the best way, the best way is  not to create new function and attach events with every render, which means it should be just

```
<div className="gallery-item" key={i} onClick={this.toggle}></div>
```

but since you need to pass the id, the best bet would be refactor it into smaller components like `<GalleryItem>`  and pass the id by `props`

Worth to read: [this](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/)

UPDATE: Also please look at comments, using `dataset.index` and `data-index` is even better

Comment: This is equally bad, `(i) => this.toggle(i)` is a new bind/function for every index and render.

Comment: @Kossel: Use `onClick={this.toggle}` just like that.

Comment: that's true. but since he need to pass argument to the toggle function, in order to have only `this.toggle` means he either has to refactor `gallery-item` to smaller component or having something flux to dispatch the  id for him, or use something outside of es6 or es7

Comment: @Kossel or just `data-index={i}` on the tag and `+e.target.dataset.index` in the event handler

Comment: @Kossel it should be `e.currentTarget.dataset.index`